# Is it possible to add exact coordinates for pinch function in XCTest class?

Tags: ios, swift, automated-tests, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I use XCTest to test zoom out of uiview (func pinch(withScale scale: CGFloat, velocity: CGFloat)) and there is a problem when above the target view there are several UIViews in the right-top and left bottom. It can't zoom out it properly and it acts as a pan, not as a pinch.

I've tried to hide the above view and it works.

```
func execute() {
    let element = self.finder.find(viewId)
    element.pinch(withScale: 0.5, velocity: -1.0)
}
```

I need to find out the way to control the coordinates when it start to zoom out or some workaround to work this well enough.